# Unable to extract email addresses from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python to get some property `titles` and their corresponding `email` address out of each container from a webpage. When I run my script, it only grabs the `titles` but in case of `email address` it scrapes only this text connected to `send eamil` button. How can I retrieve those `email addresses` as they in reality exist because when I press that `send email button`, it does send emails. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Link to that [website](https://www.angloinfo.com/singapore/directory/singapore-business-consultants-advisors-466)

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "use_above_link"

def Get_Leads(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select(".media"):
        title = items.select_one(".item-name").text.strip()
        try:
            email = items.select_one("a[alt^='Contact']").text.strip()
        except:
            email = ""
        print(title,email)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Get_Leads(URL)
```

Result I'm having like:

```
Singapore Immigration Specialist SEND EMAIL
Faithful+Gould Pte Ltd SEND EMAIL
PsyAsia International SEND EMAIL
Activpayroll SEND EMAIL
Precursor SEND EMAIL
```

Instead of the text `send email`, I expect to scrape the `email address`.

Comment: I think it is not possible because the email address is not present in the website/page source. They may be getting it by there database when you click on send email button. In other word **you are trying to scrape the thing which is not present in the web page**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The website itself does not contains the emails in code, thus you can not scrape them directly. What you can do is:

1. Gather links for websites of the companies from "Visit Website" link.
2. Scrape the homepage of those websites and search if there is any email address for contact.
3. If you did not find any email address, search for the "Contact Us" page's link.
4. Open the Contact Us page and get the email address from there.

**I played around with this concept and it worked pretty well for me as I was able to scrape email addresses of many companies**. Here's what I did:

### Scrapping Company Website's URL

Modified Your Get_Lead method. Now Get_Lead will also scrape the website URL and call a method `scrape_contact_emails(link)` which returns the email address.

```
def Get_Leads(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select(".media"):
        title = items.select_one(".item-name").text.strip()
        try:
            website = items.select_one("a[alt^='Visit Website']")['href']
        except:
            website = ""
        companies.append([title,website])
        for company,site in companies:
            try:
                print("Company: "+company+"\nWebsite: "+site+"\n"+scrape_contact_emails(site)+"\n\n--------------------\n\n")
            except:
                pass
```

### Scrapping Emails

Here's the method to scrape email address from the website. First it will search for Email Address in the homepage. There is a high probability that the email address is present in the homepage and it must be for the contact purpose. If no email address is found, it will search for Contact Us page's URL, and search for the email address there.

```
def scrape_contact_emails(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    domain = link.split(".")
    mailaddr = link
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    links = soup.find_all("a")
    contact_link = ''
    final_result = ""
    try:
        # Check if there is any email address in the homepage. 
        emails = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('.*@'+domain[1]+'.'+domain[2].replace("/","")))
        emails.sort(key=len)
        print(emails[0].replace("\n",""))
        final_result = emails[0]
    except:
        # Searching for Contact Us Page's url.
        try:
            flag = 0
            for link in links:
                if "contact" in link.get("href") or "Contact" in link.get("href") or "CONTACT" in link.get("href") or 'contact' in link.text or 'Contact' in link.text or 'CONTACT' in link.text:
                    if len(link.get("href"))>2 and flag<2:
                        flag = flag + 1
                        contact_link = link.get("href")

        except:
            pass

        domain = domain[0]+"."+domain[1]+"."+domain[2]
        if(len(contact_link)<len(domain)):
            domain = domain+contact_link.replace("/","")
        else:
            domain = contact_link

        try:
            # Check if there is any email address in the Contact Us Page. 
            res = requests.get(domain)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
            emails = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('.*@'+mailaddr[7:].replace("/","")))
            emails.sort(key=len)
            try:
                print(emails[0].replace("\n",""))
                final_result = emails[0]
                return final_result
            except:
                pass
        except Exception as e:
            pass

    return ""
```

### Output

Here's a little part of the results I got. I was not able to fetch email address for every company because some websites had protection against bots such as captcha etc. I am pretty sure this code is not perfect, just a prototype but can be improved a lot. Hope this will help you out.

```
info@zacknzul,com
Company: Zack & Zul Business Broker
Website: http://www.zacknzul.com/


--------------------


 sales@ats.com.sg
Company: ATS IT Solutions Pte Ltd - Guarantees 100% Satisfaction & W...
Website: http://www.ats.com.sg


--------------------


Info@britcham.org.sg
Company: British Chamber of Commerce - Singapore
Website: http://www.britcham.org.sg/


--------------------


Company: International Enterprise Singapore
Website: http://www.iesingapore.gov.sg/


--------------------


Company: IBS Business Consulting Pte. Ltd
Website: http://www.consultibs.sg/


--------------------


Company: Positive Performance Consulting
Website: https://www.positiveconsulting.sg


--------------------


enquiries@jaba.com.sg
Company: Jacob Business Armour Pte Ltd
Website: http://www.jaba.com.sg/
```

Comment: Instead of that biggest line within your script, try using `if "contact" in link.text.lower(): absolutelink = urljoin(sitelink,link.get('href'))`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the website it self doesn't contain email adress of that company in their HTML, try on clicking to that link and it will open their own email sending form to that particular company.

I would offer to first gather all companys urls, visit each company and then gather all the emails.

[image: html of the company in given link of your's]
As you can see there is no email
When you click on the **SEND EMAIL** it opens this companys webpage and it send I gues thrue their own system, not showing you the email to which is sent, because I can't detect it...

I gues thei are shadowing email by id on the link, `href="https://www.angloinfo.com/singapore/directory/listing/enquire/singapore-the-insight-bureau-pte-ltd"` when you click **SEND EMAIL** it opens this page https://www.angloinfo.com/singapore/directory/listing/enquire/singapore-the-insight-bureau-pte-ltd and there on **Send Message** button you can see the link that is generated and I guess pointing to their DB point where is the email of that company... `action="https://www.angloinfo.com/singapore/directory/listing/sendmessage/singapore-the-insight-bureau-pte-ltd/161535"`